# Delete file as different user under PHP

Tags: nginx, php, debian, permissions

I'm running PHP as user `www-data` and Nginx is running as user `nginx`. I need to delete files in `/var/cache/nginx/`, which is owned by user `nginx` and I want to do it using PHP.

Is there a way to allow `www-data` to delete files in `/var/cache/nginx/`?

Or is there a way to execute `rm` as user `nginx` within PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my `nginx.conf` to run Nginx as `www-data`, that did the trick.

Comment: That is a security hole.

Answer (score 2):

On the OS level you can solve this in 2 ways:

- filesystem ACL's (which are a bit hairy)
- User groups - which in my opinion are a bit easier

Steps:

- modify the init script of nginx to include `umask 007` - this will allow to create files with group writable permissions
- modify user `www-data` to be also in `nginx` group - eg `usermod -a -G nginx www-data`
- restart affected services and you should be fine.

Comment: How/where do I set `umask 007` in the nginx init script?

Comment: just edit the init script and add `umask 007`

Comment: I added `umask 007` to `/etc/init.d/nginx` and executed `usermod -a -G nginx www-data`, but PHP-FPM can't delete files/folders in `/var/cache/nginx` yet. Any more clues?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust this with extended file system access lists, e.g.

> setfacl -R -d -m u:www-data:rwX /var/cache/nginx

Comment: I tried this, but PHP-FPM still can't seem to delete files/folders in `/var/cache/nginx`.

Comment: can you update question with output of getfact /var/cache/nginx please

Comment: Here is the output: http://pastebin.com/raTC27u6